# Plotting multiple graphs by grouping values from a data frame column?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, seaborn, visualization

I am rather new to visualizations and appreciate anything and help!
I am looking at how I could make multiple plots grouping a data frame by one column and then making a plot for each unique value. E.g. for the dataset below, I would like three different plots, one for each location, and I would like to be able to label them individually. I am not quite sure how to do that. The sample data frame:

```
data = {
    "location": ["USA", "USA", "USA", "UK", "UK", 
                 "UK", "World", "World", "World"], 
    "date": ["21-06-2021", "22-06-2021", "23-06-2021", 
             "21-06-2021", "22-06-2021", "23-06-2021", 
             "21-06-2021", "22-06-2021", "23-06-2021"], 
    "number": [456, 543, 675, 543, 765, 345, 9543, 9543, 9234]
}

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['location','date','number'])
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])
```

I tried doing this. It gives me three plots, but I don't know how to label and alter the descriptions of the graph individually.

```
df.groupby("location").plot(x="date", y="number", subplots=True)
```

[image]

And in general, it would be nice if the plot looked a bit nicer, like the one below (I am referring to the line and the dot):

```
import seaborn as sns

p = sns.catplot(data=df, x='date', y="number", hue='location', kind='point');
p.fig.set_figwidth(16)
p.fig.set_figheight(6)
```

[image]

Comment: You would plot 3 figures separately with seaborn, right?

Comment: Hi !! Did your query solved? if so then try considering [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) to signal others that the issue is resolved. If not, you can provide feedback so that the answer can be improved (or removed)

Answer (score 0):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Try:

```
labels=[]
for k,v in df.groupby("location"):
    plt.plot(v["date"],v["number"],marker='o')
    labels.append(k)
    plt.legend(labels,title='location')
    plt.xticks(v["date"].unique())
```

[image]

**Note:** If you want to remove the top and right border then add this line at the end inside the for loop:

```
plt.gca().spines[['top','right']].set_visible(False)
```